# How do I resolve this "'double-conversion Groupcctype' file not found" issue?

Tags: c++, reactjs, xcode, react-native

So I've recently upgraded my React Native project and it's caused my application to not build in XCode. The version didn't change, but it seems that some files and folders are no longer present.

The error I'm getting is this from the String.cpp (third-party):

```
#include <double-conversion Groupcctype>    
'double-conversion Groupcctype' file not found
```

I've tried these solutions, (reinstalling third-party libraries) but they seem to not be working:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21168

```
$ cd node_modules/react-native/scripts && ./ios-install-third-party.sh && cd ../../../
$ cd node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/ && ../../scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh && cd ../../../../
```

I get this error in the command line when I run the first line from above:

```
./ios-install-third-party.sh: line 61: ./ios-configure-glog.sh: No such file or directory
```

I have tried other ideas, but they haven't worked either.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
#include <double-conversion Groupcctype>
```

to this:

```
#include "double-conversion.h"
```

or:

```
#include <double-conversion/double-conversion.h> // V8 JavaScript implementation
```